# Problem with creation of model with many-to-many field in serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I have `Course`, `TeacherProfile` and `StudentProfile` models with following relations:

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(
        StudentProfile,
        blank=True,
        related_name='students'
    )
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(
        TeacherProfile,
        blank=True,
        related_name='teachers'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)


class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('CoursesUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('CoursesUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I'm trying to create new course via POST request with body:

```
{
  "name": "Course",
  "students": [],
  "teachers": []
}
```

I want to add `request.user` to teachers filed
This is my view for `Course`

```py
class CourseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CourseSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(creator=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And serializer for `Course` model:

```py
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'students', 'teachers']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        creator_profile_id = TeacherProfile.objects.filter(
            user__id=validated_data['creator'].id
        )[0].id
        validated_data['teachers'].append(creator_profile_id)

        return Course(**validated_data)
```

But have

> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use students.set() instead.

I don't understand how to use ```set()`` in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is to save new model and then add ManyToMany fields.
In `CourseSerializer.create()`:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    creator_profile_id = TeacherProfile.objects.filter(
            user__id=validated_data['creator'].id
        )[0].id
    name = validated_data['name']
    course = Course(name=name)
    course.save()
    course.teachers.add(creator_profile_id)

    return course
```